# RedirectToAction is not redirecting at all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm using RedirectToAction to redirect after a post to another controller and it's working. so i tried to Redirect to another action in the same controller and it's NOT working too.

```
    public ActionResult finalize(int id)
    {
        Meeting meeting = db.Meetings.Find(id);
        meeting.meetingStatus = "finalized";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {          
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Meeting meeting)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
            db.SaveChanges();
        //    return RedirectToAction("Invitation");  
            return (RedirectToAction("finalize", new { id = meeting.meetingID}));
        }

        return View(meeting);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an `Index` method in your controller? What do you mean by `it's not working` What happens? An error?

Comment: Yes , There's an Index method in my controller 
and its redirecting to Index without redirecting to finalize first.

Comment: do what do you mean by its not working? What happens? Have you tried debugging the code at your `Redirect` call?

Comment: as i said , it should Redirect to finalize first -> then to Index but its Redirecting to index Directly.

Comment: You have default route (as in start project template) or custom route for your actions?

Comment: default . i haven't touched the global.asax file

Comment: Have you decorated your finalise method with an [HttpGet]?  Not sure 100% if that matters though.

Answer (score 0):

you cant make 2 redirects in the same call , a redirect just return an http redirect code to another page , redirecting 2 times just wont work, don't treat action methods like normal methods they are different

for example when you request a page `example.com/controller/action`

`action` will be executed and for example it has a return value with `RedirectToAction("NotFound")`

what will happen in this scenario is

`action` body will be executed and the return value will send to the client an http header of 302 that says your new destination is `/controller/NotFound`

so `RedirectToAction` just return an http code to the client its not calling another method

---

**Update**

i was wrong i checked with [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) , you can use redirect to action many times , what will happen the server will send multiple http redirect headers for each one

i jumped to conclusion this fast because i didnt think multiple redirect is the right way to do it, so after i tried it , i can say it works , just create a new project to see where is the problem exactly or use a tool like [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)